# Scala spark sftp copying crc file rather than dataframe content

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sftp

I am trying to copy dataframe to sftp location. Below is the code for the same:

```
val df:DataFrame = Seq(
  ("e1", "s1", "v1"),
  ("e1", "s1", "v1")
).toDF("email","rule","tag")

df.write.
  format("com.springml.spark.sftp").
  option("host", "SFTP-HOST").
  option("username", "SFTP-USER").
  option("password", "****").
  option("fileType", "csv").
  save("/abc/sample2.csv")
```

But the same is copying crc file rather than contents of dataframe. 
Any suggestions.

Library used: compile `com.springml:spark-sftp_2.11:1.1.0`

Comment: Any luck? Running into the same issue.